# Como selecionar apenas uma div de várias iguais com js?

Tags: javascript, html

Eu estou criando um sistema de posts feitos com **divs**, porém como todas as divs vão ter a mesma nomenclatura de classes eu preciso que quando eu clicar em alguma o javascript ataque apenas a própria sem interferir nas outras. Somente com js, não uso jquery!

Exemplo, se eu clicar em abrir o menu do post, quero que apenas esse menu abra sem abrir a dos outros posts.

Comment: Você não tem nenhum código a acrescentar? Quer fazer isso somente com js? Pode ser com jquery?

Comment: @LocalHost Infelismente não, pois ainda não sei como criar, amanhã eu ponho o código do HTML porque agora estou pelo celular!

Answer (score 2):

Com jquery o método click pega todos os elementos com determinada classe, após isso você envia o clicado por parâmetro e pega com o this...

```js
$('.ctn').click(function(e){
 alert($(this).text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ctn">
  div 1  
</div>
<div class="ctn">
  div 2
</div>
<div class="ctn">
  div 3 
</div>
<div class="ctn">
  div 4
</div>
```

Comment: Então é só usar o 'this'?

Answer (score 1):

Com JavaScript puro:

```js
var elementoAtual = document.getElementsByClassName("minha-classe");

Array.prototype.slice.call(elementoAtual).forEach(function(pegaElementoAtual){
    pegaElementoAtual.addEventListener('click', function(e){
       alert(this.innerHTML);
    });
});
```

```css
body{
    font-family: 'calibri light', sans-serif;  
}
div{
    padding: 5px;
}
div.minha-classe{
    text-align: justify;
    text-indent: 25pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="minha-classe">
    Adult education is essential for Democracy of India. The number of grown up illiterates is great. All college and senior School students should come forward to visit villages in the summer vacation. Each one will teach one there. This will remove illiteracy and strengthen our democracy.
</div>
<div class="minha-classe">
    I happened to see a one day cricket match between Pakistan and Australia at Wankhade Stadium, Mumbai. I went for a fun. But I witnessed a horrible sight. Two thousand ticketless cricket fans gate crashed. There was a stampede. Three persons died and twenty were injured. Administration was responsible for it.
</div>
<div class="minha-classe">
    City Anti-pollution Drive demands certain steps from all the citizens of ABC city. All house-holders should pack the waste in a plastic bag and put the bag in front of their house. The bag will be replaced with an empty bag by the Municipal van every morning. They should maintain the cleanliness of the city. This will make the city pollution free.
</div>
```

Você não postou código algum, mas isso pode ser facilmente elaborado com o seguinte ([**com JQuery**](http://html-tuts.com/jquery-this-selector/)):

```
$('div.minha_classe').on('click', function(){
   var elementoAtual = $(this);
   // Faça o que quiser a partir daqui
});
```

Comment: Então é só usar o 'this' ?

Comment: Basicamente! O `$(this)` se refere ao elemento do contexto atual. Isso em JQuery. Em puro Javascript é só usar a palavra [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: Obrigado! Tem como selecionar um elemento irmão a partir do 'this'?

Comment: Sim. Tem sim! Como você planeja isso?

Comment: Ficou meio confuso minha pergunta, mas no meu projeto, quando clicar num botão vai abrir um menu dentro da div, porém vão ser várias divs com as mesmas classes e não pode abrir a das outras divs!

Comment: [**Veja só isso**](https://jsfiddle.net/znx7kxkd/7/)! No lugar de somente exibir o texto você poderá facilmente fazer qualquer outra ação com o elemento HTML ou qualquer outro elemento do DOM. Tente e elabore seu próprio código, qualquer dúvida, por favor, poste novamente com uma amostra do que você tentou. Como é sabido, essa comunidade é para se tirar dúvidas e não para fazer o dever de casa de outra pessoa.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` retorna um array de itens DOM, ele não vai funcionar se fizer assim `elementoAtual.addEventListener('click'`, o correto seria usar um `for`. ;D

Comment: Pronto, @GuilhermeNascimento. Atualizando de acordo com sua sugestão.

Comment: @NotTheRealHemingway o StackSnippet ou trecho de código funciona bem semelhante ao Jsfiddle, nesse caso você deve sim usar trecho de código, ele só não vai ser util para coisas como PHP ou um Javascript que não faz nada, ou se está usando apenas para marcação de texto. Eu editei a sua resposta e removi o que não era importante, creio que não é necessario escrever coisas como "**Editado**", isso porque se notar no rodapé da resposta ele mostra a ultima vez que a resposta foi editada, recomendo também que se concentre em deixa o que é proveitoso no corpo da resposta, o que estava errado...

Comment: ...anteriormente prefira remover, assim deixa mais limpo e claro a intenção para quem pergunta ;), espero que eu tenha conseguido lhe ajudar quanto a um melhor uso do site.

Comment: Ajudou sim, @GuilhermeNascimento! Muito obrigado.